# Jhipster Elasticsearch between dates

Tags: jhipster

Does anybody can help me to find a date field in my Entity?

I set a start date and a final date and I need to find the date between that range. I'm using a Jhipster application with ElasticSearch.

It has to query the database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster's generated search method uses a Query String Query, so you can send a query to your application's API that looks like this: `query: 'dateField:[2000-01-01 TO 2000-01-02]'`.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html